# Can't compress a recycled bitmap Android

Tags: android, bitmap, upload

I'm trying to upload bitmap images, this is my code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

                    // to add a unique name to the images
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ymdHs");
                    Date now = new Date();
                    String imageName = formatter.format(now);

                    resizingImage(bitmap, imageName);
for (int a =0; a<imageResizedList.size();a++){

                        HashMap<String, Bitmap> tmpData = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
                        tmpData = imageResizedList.get(a);

                        Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
                        Iterator it = key.iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            final String imageNameKey = (String)it.next();
                            Bitmap imageBitmapValue = (Bitmap) tmpData.get(imageNameKey);

                            System.out.println("imageNameKey: "+imageNameKey +" & imageBitmapValue: "+imageBitmapValue);

                            final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(imageBitmapValue);

                            String url = "http://url/upload.php";
                            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    pDialog.hide();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    pDialog.hide();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error while uploading image: "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }){
                                @Override
                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                    params.put("image", encodedString);
                                    params.put("imageName", imageNameKey);
                                    return params;
                                }
                            };

                            // to prevent sending images twice
                            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                            myCommand.add(stringRequest);

                            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

                        }// while end


                    } // for resized bitmaps
```

to resize bitmap:

```
  private void resizingImage(Bitmap imageBitmap, String imageName){


    imageResizedList.add(getResizedBitmap(imageBitmap, imageName, 1280, 720)); // 1280 x 720
    imageResizedList.add(getResizedBitmap(imageBitmap, imageName, 1366, 768)); // 1366 x 768

}
```

the function:

```
public HashMap<String, Bitmap> getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, String imageName, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    System.out.println("newWidth: "+newWidth+" newHeight: "+newHeight);

    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    HashMap<String, Bitmap> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    hashMap.put(imageName+"_"+newHeight+"X"+newHeight+".jpg", resizedBitmap);

    return hashMap;
}
```

but it gives me the following Exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap

in this line: final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(imageBitmapValue);

How to Fix this issue?

Comment: Not recycle the bitmap.

Comment: Can't get your meaning.

Comment: Somewhere, something is calling bitmap.recycle() on your image.  If you're not done with it, you shouldn't be recycling it yet.  If you are done with it, you shouldn't be trying to compress it.

Comment: I edited my question, note that I'm using createBitmap to resize the bitmap